Query to find all locations within the radius for each location at another coordinate
We're using the geokit-rails gem to find all locations within a certain distance from another location.
class CreateLocations < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.2]
  def change
    create_table :locations do |t|
      t.decimal :lat
      t.decimal :lng
      t.float   :radius
    end
  end
end

class Location < ApplicationRecord
  acts_as_mappable
end

The following works great and returns all locations within 5 miles of (37,-122)
Location.within(5, origin: [37,-122])

We next need to find all locations within the distance stored in the radius column in Location. The following query does not work.
Location.within('locations.radius', origin: [37,-122])

Can someone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?
[Update] The solution below by @max and @engineersmnky worked great. I also discovered the "merge" function which lets you use .within across a join table. For example if a location has many products then you can search for all products sold by locations within their delivery radius to you by this. Hopefully this saves someone else a lot of time.
Product.joins(:location).merge(Location.within(Location.arel_table[:radius], origin: [37, -122]))


I'm not sure the method is even designed to work that way but you could try Location.within(Location.arel_table[:radius], origin: [37,-122]). This is where the argument ends up https://github.com/geokit/geokit-rails/blob/e3a9f6e21d1987b360f4b656d2d35cd0d5814971/lib/geokit-rails/acts_as_mappable/class_methods.rb#L164

After running through the source code a bit as @max pointed out you can use
Location.within( Location.arel_table[:radius], origin: [37,-122])

This will result in <= but it is a lot cleaner than the alternatives
The formula differs from yours though.
(ACOS(least(1,COS(#{lat})*COS(#{lng})*COS(RADIANS(#{qualified_lat_column_name}))*COS(RADIANS(#{qualified_lng_column_name}))+
COS(#{lat})*SIN(#{lng})*COS(RADIANS(#{qualified_lat_column_name}))*SIN(RADIANS(#{qualified_lng_column_name}))+
SIN(#{lat})*SIN(RADIANS(#{qualified_lat_column_name}))))*#{multiplier})

Alternatively we can use your current concept (shown in a comment) but leverage the [geokit-rails] implementation:
origin = Geokit::LatLng(37,-122)
Location.where(Location.distance_sql(origin).lt(Location.arel_table[:radius]))

If you really want to use your current formula instead (which is different than what within uses).
We can create your formula as follows:
# Including Math because otherwise I would need to create new instances of 
# Addition, Division, and Multiplication for each operation  

Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.include(Arel::Math) 

class Location < ApplicationRecord
  scope :inside_radius, ->(lat: , lng:) {
    location_table = Arel::Table.new('locations')
    q = Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('ASIN',[
      Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('SQRT',[ 
        Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('POWER',
          [
            Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new("SIN",
             [ Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new("RADIANS",[location_table[:lat] - lat])]
            ) / Arel.sql('2.0'),
            2
          ]
        ) + 
        Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('COS',[Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('RADIANS',[lat])]) *
        Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('COS',[Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('RADIANS',[location_table[:lat]])]) * 
        Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('POWER',
          [
            Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new("SIN",
             [ Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new("RADIANS",[location_table[:lng] - lng])]
            ) / Arel.sql('2.0'),
            2
          ]
        )
      ])
    ]).*(2).*(3956).lt(location_table[:radius])
    where(q)
  }
end 

Usage:
Location.inside_radius(lat: 37, lng: -122)

Produces
SELECT locations.*
FROM 
  locations 
WHERE 
ASIN(SQRT((POWER(SIN(RADIANS(([locations].[lat] - 37))) / 2.0, 2) + COS(RADIANS(37)) * COS(RADIANS([locations].[lat])) * POWER(SIN(RADIANS(([locations].[lng] - -122))) / 2.0, 2)))) * 2 * 3956 < [locations].[radius]


Just use simple location object with radius
Location.flat_map do |location|
  Location.within(location.radius, origin: [37,-122]).ids
end


We need to find all locations that are within the delivery distance (radius) for each location, not just within one radius. We have the following query hard coded and it works but we were hoping to use the geokit gem since we're using it anyway:

Location.where(Location.distance_sql, {lat: 37, lng: -122})

class Location < ApplicationRecord
def self.distance_sql
h = "POWER(SIN((RADIANS(locations.lat - :lat))/2.0),2) + " +
"COS(RADIANS(:lat)) * COS(RADIANS(locations.lat)) * " +
"POWER(SIN((RADIANS(locations.lng - :lng))/2.0),2)"
r = 3956 # Earth's radius in miles
"2 * #{r} * ASIN(SQRT(#{h})) < locations.radius"
end
end
